# In Castle Windsor, what would the installer code look like to use a method of a service to inject a dependency into another service?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

```
public class ServiceThatProvidesDep
{
    public Dep GetDep()
    {
        // return dep object
    }
}

public class ServiceThatConsumesDep
{
    public ServiceThatConsumesDep(Dep dep)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here's how I think the installer might look:

```
container.Register(Component.For<ServiceThatProvidesDep>());
container.Register(Component.For<Dep>().UsingService<ServiceThatProvidesDep>(s => s.GetDep()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this `UsingFactoryMethod` overload like this:

```
container.Register(Component.For<ServiceThatProvidesDep>());
container.Register(Component.For<ServiceThatConsumesDep>().LifestyleTransient());
container.Register(Component.For<Dep>().UsingFactoryMethod(kernel => kernel.Resolve<ServiceThatProvidesDep>().GetDep()).LifestyleTransient());
```

I added transient life cycles to components that will probably need it when you are using a factory method.

Answer (score 0):

The ServiceThatProvidesDep should instead be a Dep factory

```
public interface IDepFactory
{
    public Dep CreateDep();
}
```

and it should be injected into service that consumes it

```
public class ServiceThatUsesDep
{
    public ServiceThatUesDep( IDepFactory factory )
    ...
```

This way you are not trying to reinvent things.

Comment: I don't want to change my code to cater to the DI library: ServiceThatUsesDep's actual dependency is Dep, not IDepFactory.

Comment: Also, just because CW doesn't have this feature doesn't mean I'm reinventing anything. [Other DI libraries](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html) have this feature.

Comment: I know that. However, by "reinventing" I meant an approach where you not register services but factory methods, in other words, you left class contracts in favor of concrete method signatures.